# Как использовать два разных параметра в @Repeatable аннотации

Tags: java, аннотации

Писал вот такой код.
Задача: Создать свою аннотацию, используя аннотацию `@Repeatable` с Java 8, вызвать дважды аннотацию подтягивая разные параметры выполнить сложение 2-х чисел.

```
@MathAnno(num1 = 50)
@MathAnno(num2 = 100)
public void mathSum(int num1, int num2)
```

Вот я и написал но компилятор выдает ошибку

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "lesson8.additional.MathAnno.num1()" because "mathAnno" is null
> at lesson8.additional.Main.main(Main.java:12)

Как можно применять два разных параметра без default? Я знаю,ошибка выдается из-за того, что я на аннотаций по дефолту поставил 0. Не подскажете как по другому написать?

```java
package lesson8.additional;

import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Math math = new Math();
        Class<?> cl = Math.class;
        Method method = cl.getDeclaredMethod("MathSum", int.class, int.class);
        MathAnno mathAnno = method.getAnnotation(MathAnno.class);
        math.MathSum(mathAnno.num1(), mathAnno.num2());
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface MathAnnos{
    MathAnno[] value();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Repeatable(MathAnnos.class)
@interface MathAnno{
    int num1() default 0;
    int num2() default 0;
}

class Math{
    @MathAnno(num1 = 50, num2 = 0)
    @MathAnno(num1 = 0, num2 = 100)
    public void MathSum(int num1, int num2){
        System.out.println(num1 + num2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ошибка выдается из-за того, что я на аннотации по дефолту поставил 0.

Нет, вовсе не из-за этого.

Вы, судя по коду, ожидаете, что две аннотации

```
@MathAnno(num1 = 50, num2 = 0)
@MathAnno(num1 = 0, num2 = 100)
```

как бы "схлопнутся" в одну

```
@MathAnno(num1 = 50, num2 = 100)
```

, потому что запрашиваете один экземпляр аннотации: `MathAnno mathAnno = method.getAnnotation(MathAnno.class);`

Но это работает не так. Давайте взглянем на [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html).

> There are several methods available in the Reflection API that can be used to retrieve annotations. The behavior of the methods that return a single annotation, such as AnnotatedElement.getAnnotation(Class), are unchanged in that they only return a single annotation if one annotation of the requested type is present. If more than one annotation of the requested type is present, you can obtain them by first getting their container annotation.

> Доступно несколько методов в Reflection API, которые можно использовать дл извлечения аннотаций.  Поведение методов, возвращающих одну аннотацию, таких как AnnotatedElement.getAnnotation(Class), не меняется, в том смысле, что они возвращают одну аннотацию, если только одна аннотация данного типа присутствует у элемента. Если у элемента более одной аннотации данного типа, вы можете получить их, запросив их контейнерную аннотацию.

Таким образом `method.getAnnotation(MathAnno.class)` сработает только если y элемента одна аннотация. В вашем же случае надо воспользоваться `MathAnnos annos = method.getAnnotation(MathAnnos.class)`, чтобы получить контейнер с массивом аннотаций.

Если вы заранее не знаете, сколько будет аннотаций, то `MathAnno[] annos = method.getAnnotationsByType(MathAnno.class)`, чтобы получить сразу массив.

В первом случае код будет выглядеть так:

```
MathAnnos mathAnno = method.getAnnotation(MathAnnos.class);
math.MathSum(mathAnno.value()[0].num1(), mathAnno.value()[1].num2());
```

во вотором — так:

```
MathAnno[] mathAnnos = method.getAnnotationsByType(MathAnno.class);
math.MathSum(mathAnnos[0].num1(), mathAnnos[1].num2());
```

Разумеется, для произвольного случая, вам придется озадачиться проверкой количества аннотаций в массиве и вытаскивать дефолтные значения. Хотя бы как-то так:

```
MathAnno[] mathAnnos = method.getAnnotationsByType(MathAnno.class);
int arg1 = mathAnnos.length > 0 ? arg1 = mathAnnos[0].num1() : (Integer) MathAnno.class.getDeclaredMethod("num1").getDefaultValue();
int arg2 = mathAnnos.length > 1 ? mathAnnos[1].num2() : (Integer) MathAnno.class.getDeclaredMethod("num2").getDefaultValue();
    math.MathSum(arg1, arg2);
```

---

После вышесказанного, хочется добавить, что использование у каждой аннотации по счету своего параметра выглядит неуклюже. Если кто-то поменяет строки с аннотациями местами все сломается. Чуть более изящным вариантом было бы ровно одно `value()` у аннотации `@MathAnno`:

```
@interface MathAnno{
    int value() default 0;
}

class Math{
    @MathAnno(50) @MathAnno(100)
    public void mathSum(int num1, int num2){
        System.out.println(num1 + num2);
    }
}

Math math = new Math();
Class<?> cl = Math.class;
Method method = cl.getDeclaredMethod("mathSum", int.class, int.class);
MathAnno[] mathAnnos = method.getAnnotationsByType(MathAnno.class);
int arg1 = mathAnnos.length > 0 ? mathAnnos[0].value() : (Integer) MathAnno.class.getDeclaredMethod("value").getDefaultValue();
int arg2 = mathAnnos.length > 1 ? mathAnnos[1].value() : (Integer) MathAnno.class.getDeclaredMethod("value").getDefaultValue();
math.mathSum(arg1, arg2);
```

---

PS. Существует отдельная [спецификация](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eabuckley/jep120/8misc.pdf) на `@Repeatable` аннотации. Она, в частности, гарантирует, что возвращаемые `getAnnotationsByType` аннотации сохранят тот же порядок, что был в исходном коде.

PPS. Это интересное учебное задание, но в реальной жизни с таким можно столкнуться только при разработке своих библиотек/фреймворков, поведение которых управляется аннотациями.

Comment: Спасибо большое теперь начинаю понимать как вообще реализовать аннотацию